# How to fill entire frame with an image?

Tags: image, emacs, window

I am creating an Emacs frame with `(make-frame)` and loading an image into it. When I start Emacs with `-q` option and run my script, Emacs creates a frame and fills the entire frame with the image.

However when I run this from my ordinary Emacs session (`emacsclient`), then Emacs inserts `1` to the left of the image and creates a column over entire height of the frame to the left of the image:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9312e.jpg)

Below is my code to create a frame and insert an image:

```
(defvar bckgimg "~/a.jpg" "Image used for desktop background")
(progn
    (setq backgr-frame
          (make-frame
           `((name . "background-frame")
             (width . ,(display-pixel-width))
             (height . ,(display-pixel-height))
             (undecorated . t)
             (fringe . nil)
             (below . t)
             (left-fringe . 0)
             (right-fringe . 0)
             (tool-bar-lines . 0)
             (menu-bar-lines . 0)
             (unsplittable . t)
             (mode-line . nil)
             (buffer-predicate . (lambda (x) nil))
             (internal-border-width . 0)
             (z-group . below)
             (visibility . nil)
             (skip-taskbar . t)
             (minibuffer . nil)
             (top . 0)
             (left . 0))))

    (with-selected-frame backgr-frame
            (toggle-frame-maximized)
            (lower-frame backgr-frame)
            (make-frame-visible backgr-frame)
            (with-output-to-temp-buffer "backgr"
                    (switch-to-buffer "backgr")
                    (setq mode-line-format nil)
                    (if (fboundp 'display-line-numbers-mode)
                                    (display-line-numbers-mode -1))
                    (if (fboundp 'linnum-mode)
                                    (linnum-mode -1))
                    (insert-image (create-image bckgimg
                                                'jpeg nil
                                                :width 3840)))))
```

I have being looking into docs and searching around but I can't seem to find how to fix this. What would be the code to display the image without that extra column to the left (green in screenshot)?

Comment: Tag `elisp` is not just for asking how to do something that involves Emacs Lisp.

Comment: Excuse me Drew, I am not really with you. What tag elisp exactly is for is not defined, and I am sure it stands for many things. I am also sure that asking for help about elisp programming and Emacs API is ONE of those things, so I am quite sure this should be tagged as both emacs and elisp.

Comment: The `elisp` tag is for questions specifically about the Emacs-Lisp language, which is a particular dialect of Lisp. Pretty much *every* question about using Emacs is about using Elisp or can be answered with reference to Elisp code. Your question about Emacs is creating a frame and inserting an image into it. Your question naturally includes Elisp code, and so will the answers. It's not a question *about* Elisp.

Comment: If every Emacs question that touches on Elisp were tagged `elisp` then the tag would be meaningless and unhelpful. Click the tag to see what kind of questions are tagged with it (and yes, yours is not the only question mistagged with it).

Comment: FWIW, you might want to show (e.g. link to) the image you create, and perhaps an image of the correct appearance you get with `emacs -q` etc. And the image you do link to is incomprehensible to me (FWIW) - it doesn't seem to correspond to your description. Finally, is all of the code you include necessary to reproduce the problem? If not then you might want to pare it down, to help others help you.

Comment: I have seen questions under Elisp tag, and I see many questions like mine. Tag description perfectly describes my use case. So, with all respect to you Drew A., thanks for all the +-libraries and Emacs contributions you have done, I really admire you, but you are misinterpreting meaning of the tag and it's usage. I don't agree with you that Elisp should be used just for the questions of "language nature" since it is such a small niche language. How many times can one ask how to define a variable or write a loop? Being so narrow as you demand, does not make the tag very useful.

Comment: If Elisp had a depth and universality of language like say C++ I might agree with your concern. But in such a small niche language being so narrow is rather contra productive since Elisp without Emacs practically does not make much sense. You also tagged my post with "image" tag, which is completely wrong. Just look at kind of questions asked there, it has nothing to do with Elisp and Emacs API.

Comment: The last point is that we are obviously interpreting meaning of a tag itself differently. For you tag seem to be used as some kind of precise categorization tool, where things are cut in stone and have to obey some precise laws. For me a tag is a fuzzy tool that is used to bring a question to notice for certain audience of people. As such I would like to bring my question to two groups of people where I might get help to solve it: emacs group and elisp group. It make sense to ask there. So please be nice and let me ask where it make sense and let be my tags. Please. Thank  you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have solved it with help from someone on Reddit. The issue was with line numbers. I had global-display-line-numbers-mode on. Adding

```
(display-line-numbers-mode -1)
```

solves the issue. I have edited code above for correct solution.